# How can I get php-cs-fixer to work for a Symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, php-cs-fixer

I installed `php-cs-fixer` globally by running

```
$ wget http://cs.sensiolabs.org/download/php-cs-fixer-v2.phar -O php-cs-fixer
```

followed by running

```
$ sudo chmod a+x php-cs-fixer
$ sudo mv php-cs-fixer /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer
```

When I try to run `php-cs-fixer` with

```
$ php-cs-fixer -vv fix /home/xxx/host/master/src/AppBundle/Command/GenerateERPContractInvoicesCommand.php --config=sf2
```

this results in the following error message:

> [PhpCsFixer\ConfigurationException\InvalidConfigurationException (16)]
>       Cannot read config file "sf2"

An attempt to run with `--config=sf23` results in the same error message.

Trying to run like this

```
$ php-cs-fixer fix src/AppBundle/Command/GenerateERPContractInvoicesCommand.php --level=symfony
```

results in the error message

> The "--level" option does not exist.

Then I create a configuration file`.php_cs` with the content

```
<?php

$finder = Symfony\CS\Finder::create()
    ->exclude([
        'app', 
        'spec', 
        'build', 
        'bin', 
        'web', 
        'vendor',
    ])
    ->in(__DIR__);

return Symfony\CS\Config::create()
    ->fixers([
        'short_array_syntax', 
        '-phpdoc_align',
        'ordered_use',
    ])
    ->finder($finder);
```

and receive the following error message:

> [PhpCsFixer\ConfigurationException\InvalidConfigurationException]
>        The config file: "/home/ivan/host/master/.php_cs" does not return a "PhpCsFixer\ConfigInterface" instance. Got: "integer".

How do I use `php-cs-fixer` for Symfony, can you help?

Where can I get the configuration for Symfony, and how do I correctly use `php-cs-fixer` for a Symfony project ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation, you may want to run with `rules` argument :

```
php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/project --rules=@Symfony
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following command in our ci dev builds:

```sh
php-cs-fixer fix --using-cache=no --rules=@Symfony src
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are doing all your work (cli params, config file) like for PHP CS Fixer v1, yet you are downloading v2.
If you want to know how to migrate, check out upgrade guide:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/UPGRADE.md